# Matlab simplify - why does it remove fractions?

Tags: matlab, symbolic-math, simplify

I am recently working with Matlab's `Symbolic Toolbox`, but encountered a big problem. I have some example code:

```
syms s w;
G = 0.1253/(s^4 + 0.5816*s^3 + 1.1691*s^2 + 0.4048*s + 0.177)
L1=diff(G)
L2=subs(L1,s,-s)
M2=subs(G,s,-s)
Ts=(-1/2)*((L1/G)+(L2/M2))
T=subs(Ts,s,1i*w)
Ts = simplify(T)
```

Everything is working well, except for the part with `T=subs(Ts,s,1i*w)` and `T=subs(Ts,s,1i*w)`. In order to calculate `i` as `i^2 = -1`, I have to use `simplify`, but then all of the fractions disappear.

Is there any other function to do what I need? Or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Can't find `i` variable in your code? what is the expected output?

Comment: `i`is a imaginary part of this symbolic expression. Expected output is without it - only the symbolic `w` stays.

Comment: What's wrong with the fractions disappearing when you simplify? What are you actually trying to accomplish?

Comment: The result 'Ts' looks like this: 
`(58160000*w^6 - 53445144*w^4 + 16442208*w^2 + 7164960)/(100000000*w^8 - 199994144*w^6 + 124993145*w^4 - 24999836*w^2` 
when it should be like this:
 `(0.5816*w^6 - 0.53445144*w^4 + 0.16442208*w^2 + 0.07164960)/(w^8 - 0.199994144*w^6 + 0.124993145*w^4 - 0.24999836*w^2)`